# Is there a way to wrap Html.CheckboxFor, Html.TextboxFor, etc. methods with custom logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, expression-trees

I am working with legacy models that wrap data and meta-data up in a single property.  For the purpose of this question, suppose the interface is:

```
pubic interface ILegacyCheckbox 
{
   bool Value { get; set; }
   bool Editable { get; set; }
}
```

I want to wrap the CheckBoxFor() extension method with my own,

```
public static MvcHtmlString LegacyCheckboxFor<TModel>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, ILegacyCheckbox>> expression)
{
    // wrap html.CheckBoxFor() method here by extracting the Value  
    // property and check if Editable is false, in which case add 
    // an htmlAttribute of "disabled=true"
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this?  Where would I start?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LegacyCheckboxFor<TModel>(
this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
Expression<Func<TModel, ILegacyCheckbox>> expression)
{
    var parameterName = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
    var compiled = expression.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);

    if (editable)
        return html.CheckBox(parameterName, compiled.Value);
    else
        return html.CheckBox(parameterName, compiled.Value, new {disabled = "disabled"});
}
```

You may also wish to cache the compiled expression.

My example uses Html.CheckBox(); I'm not sure how to go about utilising CheckBoxFor(). I haven't got time to investigate it either, but atleast this is somewhere to start.

Comment: Do I need to wrap the parameterName with html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName() to make sure that it works in foreach loops?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MvcHtmlString LegacyCheckboxFor<TModel>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, ILegacyCheckbox>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    string parameterName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

    var checkbox = expression.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);

    return new MvcHtmlString(
        string.Format(
        "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\" {2} />",
            parameterName,
            checkbox.Value,
            checkbox.Editable ? "disabled=true" : string.Empty));
}
```

Comment: I would use the Html.CheckBox() method instead of building a string!

Comment: @Simon Bartlett how would I reference `Html.CheckBox()` within this extension?

Comment: @Simon Bartlett Wouldn't that only work if the argument was `HtmlHelper` and not `HtmlHelper<TModel>`? There is no Intellisense showing `CheckBox` as a method

Comment: @David it does work, I just wrote it in Visual Studio myself. You need to import System.Web.Mvc.Html

Comment: @Simon Barlett Doh!--only had System.Web.Mvc